# Is there any way to customize embedded Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter, widget

I'd like to add a simple text-based twitter feed to the footer of my website. From what I've read, you must generate the code for the feed through twitter, but the customization options seem extremely limited. Is there another way possible? This is the result I currently have:

http://www.charissasantos.la/mezcaleria.html

I'd like to change the background, decrease the height, remove the username photos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Javascript library, which lets you add custom CSS to the twitter embed widget. https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1

Comment: superb! have you had any joy at removing the scrollbars and limiting the number of tweets on display?

Comment: I used an nth-child { display: none } selector to just hide the "load more" and "show all" tweets

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your css into iframe:

```
resources (twitter iframe)
$(window).on('load', function() {
      $('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find('head').append('<link href="http://website.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this help you

Here is a sample code and demo you can use for search in twitter

http://www.codexworld.com/create-custom-twitter-widget-using-php/

you can also look into this examle may be this will full fill your requirement . http://dev.kim-maida.com/twitter/

here is demo code and code sample link. https://github.com/kmaida/twitter-timeline-php

Answer (score 0):

Follow the simple steps given in [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines) for various kinds of timelines that can generate twitter widgets. Please follow these steps to create custom timeline widgets as well.