# slow scrolling in twitter widget

Tags: twitter, widget

Im using the Twitter widget in a web app and it scrolls really bad-slow and I have tried to set webkit-overflow-scrolling on a surrounding div and on every tag that the widget loads in the iframe, but nothing helps. I dont know what Im missing, but setting webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; on the right tag should make it scroll good.

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please use these customize twitter widget or use customize twitter feed .
look into these answers .

1) [Is there any way to customize embedded Twitter feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865972/is-there-any-way-to-customize-embedded-twitter-feed/33516292#33516292)

2 ) [Dynamic timeline selection for embedded timelines - Hashtag Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446833/dynamic-timeline-selection-for-embedded-timelines-hashtag-timeline/33516239#33516239)

May be this help you

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow:"auto" or overflow-y:"scroll" in the surrounding div for vertical scrolling after re-size twitter widget