# Dynamic timeline selection for embedded timelines - Hashtag Timeline

Tags: twitter, widget, twitter-oauth

I've followed the guide [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18411) to add multiple widgets using the same widget id and this works perfectly fine for User timeline.

Snippet ----

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/benward" data-widget-id="[id]" data-screen-name="benward">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/endform" data-widget-id="[id]" data-screen-name="endform">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/kang" data-widget-id="[id]" data-screen-name="kang">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/brianellin" data-widget-id="[id]" data-screen-name="brianellin">
```

What I would want to do is do the same( show different widgets ) for multiple hashtags - #MH17, #MH370 on the same page. But these tags change for each article on a page.

I want to know if either of these is possible.

1. Can I make the same guide available for a search query to [this](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23MH17) and [this](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23MH370) without creating a widget manually from the Twitter page. Timeline changes when I change the "data-screen-name" property. Is there something like "data-hashtag-name"?
2. Is it possible to use Twitter API or something to automate the process of creating a widget from the browser using Auth Token - Secret?

Answer (score 1):

May be this help you .
Here i am sending you some example using this I am get json and render html div

[image]

Here is a sample code and demo you can use for search in twitter

1) http://www.codexworld.com/create-custom-twitter-widget-using-php/

2)you can also look into this examle may be this will full fill your requirement .
http://dev.kim-maida.com/twitter/

3) here is demo code and code sample link.
https://github.com/kmaida/twitter-timeline-php

Answer (score -1):

did you see these pages?

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/search

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/search

You can do this:

## corgi is the sample hashtag:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/corgi" data-widget-id="612280670367301632">#corgi Tweets</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: you can automate the hashtag name using javascript, changing the href with a variable.

Comment: Please read the documentation. It clearly says "Create a new embedded search timeline from your logged-in account’s widget settings."